# Workflow task, add other actions next to "View more actions"

Tags: workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share

Is it possible to have additional actions like "Edit Properties" in a workflow task next to "View more actions" ?
I have introduced this [Digital Signing Alfresco plugin](https://github.com/rouxemmanuel/DigitalSigning) , and I would offer the user to sign document without leaving the current task.
**Edit:**
Alfresco5.0d

Comment: Alfresco men must be on vacation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own custom control.
Copy the default control **org\alfresco\components\form\controls\workflow\packageitems.ftl** and add your buttons to it.

The import part is the following:

```
<#if packageItemActionGroup == "read_package_item_actions" || packageItemActionGroup == "edit_package_item_actions">
         <#local actions = actions + [viewMoreAction]>
      <#elseif packageItemActionGroup == "remove_package_item_actions" || packageItemActionGroup == "start_package_item_actions" || packageItemActionGroup == "edit_and_remove_package_item_actions">
         <#local actions = actions + [viewMoreAction]>
         <#local allowRemoveAllAction = true>
         <#local allowRemoveAction = true>
      <#elseif packageItemActionGroup >
      <#else>
         <#local actions = actions + [viewMoreAction]>      
      </#if>
```

The simplest way is to change the following line:

```
<#local viewMoreAction = { "name": "view_more_actions", "label": "form.control.object-picker.workflow.view_more_actions", "link": documentLinkResolver }>
```

And to add the new custom action next to or before the **view_more_actions**.